# How to implement type-safe extensible type system in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, extensibility

I'm writing a project in Scala. This project involves a set of *features* and a set of *configurations*, both extensible. By "extensible" I mean that I'm going to add new features in the hierarchy later, and they have to work with any configuration without recompilation. Here's the feature hierarchy for the following illustration:

```scala
trait Feature {
    def apply(board: Board)
}

class Foo extends Feature {
    def apply(board: Board) {
        println(board formatted "Foo: %s")
    }
}

class Bar extends Feature {
    def apply(board: Board) {
        println(board formatted "Bar: %s")
    }
}
```

A configuration basically just defines a lot of parameters for a `Board`, including initial feature count for each `Feature`. There are several possible strategies to create a configuration at run-time: predefined, random, with user-provided values, etc. In theory, I want to be able to write something like this (not a valid Scala code!):

```scala
abstract class Config(val param: Int) {
    val ConfigParameter: Int
    def featureCount[T <: Feature]: Int
}

object Config {
    def makeBasic(param: Int) = new Config(param) {
        val ConfigParameter = param
        def featureCount[Foo] = 3
        def featureCount[Bar] = 7
    }
    def makeRandom(param: Int) = new Config(param) { ... }
    def makeWithUserValues(param: Int, ...) = new Config(param) { ... }
    def makeByStandardISO1234567(param: Int) = new Config(param) { ... }
}

class Board(val config: Config) { ... }
```

Obviously, it doesn't compile. My question is: what's the best way to represent this extensible system in Scala? I can always include something like `Map[Class, Int]` in the `Config`, but it isn't type-safe: a programmer can insert classes in such `Map` that aren't `Feature`s. So, is there a way in the Scala type system to represent something like `Map[Class[T <: Feature], Int]` where different keys in the `Map` could be of different `Feature` subtypes? Alternatively, maybe there's some way to move all this behavior to the `Feature` hierarchy?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... is there a type system that is not type safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ClassManifest` (`ClassTag` in Scala 2.10) to improve your map solution:

```
package object features {
  type FeatureMap = Map[Class[_ <: Feature], Int]
}

abstract class Config(val param: Int) {
    def ConfigParameter: Int
    def featureMap: FeatureMap
    def featureCount[T<:Feature]( implicit man: ClassManifest[T] ): Int = 
      featureMap( man.erasure )
}

object Config {
    def makeBasic(param: Int) = new Config(param) {
        val ConfigParameter = param
        lazy val featureMap: FeatureMap = Map(
            classOf[Foo] -> 3,
            classOf[Bar] -> 7
        )
    }
}
```

Each time you call `featureCount` the compiler will use the right classManifest for the type you passed between brackets. The `erasure` method returns the coresponding class.

Remark: Avoid abstract vals, it has annoying effects and can break binary compatibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't compile: `man.erasure` returns `Class[_]`, but `featureMap.apply` requires `Class[_ <: Feature]`.

Comment: @Skiminok You can remove the type constraint of the map because it is already expressed in `featureCount`. If you want to make sure that inserted values are subclasses of `Feature`, you can replace `classOf` by a method returning the corresponding class manifest erasure. If it's not clear enough, I can provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `Map`-based solution (although maybe it's not the most elegant one):

```scala
package object features {
    type FeatureMap = Map[Class[_ <: Feature], Int]
}

abstract class Config(val param: Int) {
    val ConfigParameter: Int
    val FeatureCount: FeatureMap
}

object Config {
    def makeBasic(param: Int) = new Config(param) {
        val ConfigParameter = param
        lazy val FeatureCount: FeatureMap = Map(
            classOf[Foo] -> 3,
            classOf[Bar] -> 7
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need the map to know about each key's specific subtype of `Feature`? For example, here's how I'd write this:

```
trait Feature { def apply(board: Board) }

case object Foo extends Feature {
  def apply(board: Board) { printf("Foo: %s", board) }
}

case object Bar extends Feature {
  def apply(board: Board) { printf("Bar: %s", board) }
}

// ...
val featureCount: Map[Feature, Int] = Map(Foo -> 3, Bar -> 7)
```

Now you can just write `featureCount(Foo)`, `featureCount.get(Bar)`, etc. You could even type the map as `Map[Feature with Singleton, Int]` if you wanted to be sure that no non-object values can sneak in.

Alternatively, if you really wanted a map keyed on types, you could do something like this with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
trait Feature

case class Foo(count: Int) extends Feature
case class Bar(count: Int) extends Feature

import shapeless._

object featureWithCount extends Poly0 {
  implicit def foo = at(Foo(3))
  implicit def bar = at(Bar(7))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> featureWithCount[Foo]
res0: Foo = Foo(3)

scala> featureWithCount[Bar]
res1: Bar = Bar(7)
```

I'm not sure that buys you much here, though.